# rails no devuelve datos a filtros.js.erb con ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

No se ejecuta ese `alert` debería ejecutarse después de la ejecución del método filtros:

```
def filtros
    @apps= App.where(rol: params[:rol])
    .or(App.where(plataforma:params[:plataforma])
    .or(App.where(area: params[:area])))

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js{ render :json => @apps }
    end
end
```

**Vista:**

```
app/views/apps/filtros.js.erb
alert( "message" );
```

Comment: @fedorqui Vaya vista! muchas gracias por la edición y además por el comentario.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla ¡gracias a ti por mejorar las publicaciones!

Comment: ¿Y que retorna? ¿has revisado en la consola de tu explorador lo que devuelve el request? Agrega el código que está realizando la petición, porque también puede estar el problema ahí

Answer (score 0):

Sería mejor si das una breve descripción de lo que deseas hacer con ese método dado que generalmente el render js se usa para entregar parciales por ajax.

Adicionalmente no estas entregando el archivo js, ya que en la linea:

```
format.js{ render :json => @apps }
```

Lo que estas diciendo es que si te solicitan esa vista en formato javascript no retorne la vista sino la variable @apps en formato json; para usar @app dentro del script que quieres retornar basta con llamarlo en la vista, quedaría algo así :

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render layout: false}
end
```

Vista(el archivo de la vista debe terminar en .js.erb):

```
alert("<%=@apps.to_json %>");
```